# How to clone git repository with GitLab CI-CD or how to deploy spring-boot project on AWS server?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gitlab, web-deployment

I try to deploy the spring-boot project with GitLab CI/CD. But can't find any information that can help me.

So, I try to figure out how I can do it and created an AWS instance and run the `gitlub-runner` on it.

I created `.gitlab-ci.yml` and can copy files to the S3-bucket:

```
variables:
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: "awesome-proj"
deploy:
  script: aws s3 cp ./ s3://awesome-proj/ --acl bucket-owner-full-control --no-sign-request --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.html"
  tags:
    - Tag1
```

I figure out I can use the console in a similar way and clone my project to the AWS server. I decided to clone the project from the git repo and build him on the server with 'maven'.

So I try to clone the project:

```
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: "awesome-proj"
deploy:
  script: 
    - sudo cd /home/ec2-user/aweproject
    - sudo git init
    - sudo git clone https://gitlab.com/lTer/cicdtestdev.git
  tags:
    - Tag1
```

These scripts even copied some data once.

[image]

For the second time, I got the error, but it is doesn't matter now. The problem is that I haven't any files after `git clone...`. So it not works how I hoped.

- How to correctly use the console with `GitLab-runner` or deploy the project (spring-boot) with Gitlab ci/cd to the AWS?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get GitLab's CI to compile and deploy your project to a bucket? If so, that's really easy. Also, you can use [GitLab artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) if you don't specifically need to deploy to S3 or some other place.

Comment: @PierreD Yes, I only try to get GitLab Ci to complete and deploy my project.

Comment: @PierreD Not so easy if nobody knows how exactly it works

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you don't need to clone your project. When your CI pipeline runs, it already has the appropriate clone (of a branch, or the master, of whatever the CI has been instructed to run on).

The only thing you need is to compile and then deploy. For instance:

```
stages:
  - compile
  - deploy

compile:
  stage: compile
  script: mvn ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
    expire_in: 1 week

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: aws s3 sync build/ s3://somebucket/some_place/build/
```

Of course, in real life, you may want to have a specific stage for testing etc.

Comment: Many thanks. As I know I can manually deploy project on the server with command `mvn packaje` and launch it with commnad `java -jar projectName.jar`. So in the compile script I need to use command `mvn package`. But where I need to use `java -jar....`?

Comment: I try you example and get are warnings like `failed to remove cicdtestdev/.git/branches: Permission denied` when script trying `Reinitialized existing Git repository....`

Comment: `java -jar some.jar` is to _run_ the package.

Comment: Yes, I run package - and then I can use my project and get to the pages by URL. Can I deploy the project in other way?

Comment: Anyway - I do not use `java -jar ...` now. I use your example with command `mvn package` and got `Permission denied` error. How to correctly use your example?